# How to get a language-neutral locale in JS Intl API

Tags: javascript, locale

I encountered cases where I wanted to use something from the [Intl JavaScript API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl), for example to do case-insensitive comparison, but where there is no particular language that should be followed.

(That is, the logic of the operation is that it should happen the same for everyone everywhere, regardless of their locale settings.)

Usually I don’t want any Unicode normalization (for example, I want composed and decomposed forms of accented letters to be distinct), but sometimes it would make sense to merge them, although without any language-specific behavior.

In the docs I always find explanations about how to pick a language, and all sorts of variants, but I can’t find any way of saying *don’t use any language-specific behavior*. Not specifying a locale usually means “pick whatever the user has as a default”, which is exactly not what I want.

In general I pick “en-US” as a default, it probably doesn’t do anything very weird, but it feels wrong to use that when I really mean “no language”.

Basically, I want the equivalent of [Java’s Locale.ROOT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#ROOT) in JavaScript.

Comment: I believe you're supposed to be able to use the `und` language tag, but in current Chrome the various APIs just fall back to the UI language for me, whatever the `localeMatcher` option is set to.